# TSql Query for Time Range

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a simple table with bunch of applicants, where they have their Start Time, End Time and Date data. I want to figure out who is available for a specific date within a Time Range.

Table below shows where Start and End Date Columns tells us they are booked for that Date/Time .........

```
AppID        StartTime         EndTime         Date
H12            8:00             13:00          12/1/2013
H12            14:00            16:00          12/1/2013
H12            19:00            21:00          12/1/2013
H14            17:00            18:00          12/1/2013
H13            14:00            16:00          12/1/2013
H13            11:00            15:00          12/2/2013
H15            8:00             13:00          12/2/2013
```

So in the Table above how can I write a Query that will say...Give me all the applications for 12/1/2013 which are **NOT** working between 17:00 - 18:00? So basically it should return H12 & H13 (Because its time slot for 17-18 pm is not available within table for 12/1/2013).

Comment: I don't understand what do you want as result. You say that it should return H13 but you want apps for `12/1/2013`, there is an inconsistence. Also why don't you use complete DateTimes?

Comment: there are two entries for H13. one is for 12/1/2013

Comment: Lucio, I am getting data from a 3rd party in the format above, I guess I can write a custom script to append DATE column to StartTime and EndTime, but I dont think that could really help? H13, has multiple entries above with different dates. it does not have any Start/End Time between 17:00-18:00 for 12/1/2013

Comment: What if the app starts one day and finish another day? Who do you store that event?

Comment: No it has to start and END the SAME day....all I want to do is "Return the results for a Date where Start Time and END Time is Empty/Available". in simple English...tell me via query who is available between 17pm - 18pm for 12/1/2013. I am trying to query as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the apps ID which were not working at a time range on a specific date.

```sql
SELECT
    [AppID] = FreeApps
FROM table_name t1
    WHERE AppID NOT IN (-- Not in the set of apps that were busy at the time range
        SELECT AppID
        FROM table_name t2
            WHERE ((StartTime >= '17:00' AND StartTime <= '18:00')
                  OR (EndTime >= '17:00' AND EndTime <= '18:00'))
              AND Date = '12/1/2013'
              AND t1.AppID=t2.AppID)
GROUP BY AppID
```

Comment: you also have to check for the Date 12/1/2013

Comment: and you most probably also have to enclose the timestamps with ' '. don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for the typo! About the date I really don't know what the OP want to as result.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH t1 as
(
SELECT DISTINCT AppID 
FROM <table>
WHERE date = '20130112'
)
SELECT AppID 
FROM t1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM <table> t2
WHERE t2.STARTTIME < '18:00'
AND t2.ENDTIME > '17:00'
AND t1.AppID = t2.AppID
AND t2.date = '20130112'
)
```